# How to handle if Asp:.Net Core API crashed during building Host

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I have an Asp.Net Core API, currently .Net 6.

Basically Program.cs is the form like below.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = BuildWebHost(args).Build();
        host.Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.Limits.MinRequestBodyDataRate = new MinDataRate(100, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            })
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
}
```

In the Startup class, we have some boot code that needs access to a database to get hold on various settings we need during startup.

The API is hosted inside IIS, using the AspNetCoreModuleV2 handler.

If the database is unavailable, the executable will stop if I just run the API as an executable.

Inside IIS though, the API starts, then crashes, and then IIS reports 500. Which is correct.

But the process with the API doesn't get killed, but is kept alive for some reason.

So now I have a "dead", bad-configured API executable that failed to startup connected to IIS application pool.

So if I refresh website, then IIS just instantly reports 500 again.

This means that if my database is offline in the timeframe the API starts, then we manually have to restart the API before it starts responding again.

Are there any good solutions to avoid this either in web.config or by signaling from inside the .Net Code that "I'm dead" - try to restart me.

The options in the AspNetCore tag doesn't seem to do the trick - or I am tuning it wrong.
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/web-config?view=aspnetcore-7.0#attributes-of-the-aspnetcore-element)

In best of worlds IIS would keep reporting 500 in e.g. 2-5 minutes, then try to start the executable again, and then continue like that until database is up again.

Best regards
/Anders

(edit)
Is still interested in something/some way IIS can handle this so we don't have to build extra infrastructure around it.

But inspired by Jerrys script below, I made a modified version that looks up all processes running with my executable name, I can find the site from the process Username, remove "iis apppool", and then ping each site. (most posted here for my own reference)

This doesn't restart anything just loops through our sites as a manual process for now so we dont have to check all of them one by one.

Will be easy to extend to connect Application Pool and Process User Name so it also can restart if it reports anything but 200.

```
$apiProcesses = Get-Process NAME_OF_YOUR_EXECUTABLE -IncludeUserName

foreach($process in $apiProcesses)
{
    $siteDomain = $process.userName -replace "IIS APPPOOL\\", ""
    Write-Host ("Checking $siteDomain")
     
    $testUri = "https://$siteDomain/api/license"

    $Request = [system.Net.WebRequest]::Create($testUri)

    try {
        # Get the response
        $Response = $Request.GetResponse()
    } catch [System.Net.WebException] {
        # If it fails, get Response from the Exception
        $Response = $_.Exception.InnerException.Response
    }

    if(200 -ne ($Response.StatusCode -as [int])){
        Write-Host "          Site $testUri seems down" 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Database offline with not cause crash of the application pool. IIS does not have built in method to detect error 500.
You can make a PowerShell script to check the response code every 5 minutes, then if it is 500, restart the application pool.

```
# Loop indefinitely
while ($true) {
    Write-Host "checking status"

    $App = (Get-Website 'Default Web Site')

    # Uri for the application
    $TestUri = 'http://localhost/api/weatherforecast' -f $App.path

    # Create WebRequest
    $Request = [system.Net.WebRequest]::Create($TestUri)
    try {
        # Get the response
        $Response = $Request.GetResponse()
    } catch [System.Net.WebException] {
        # If it fails, get Response from the Exception
        $Response = $_.Exception.InnerException.Response
    }

    # The numerical value of the StatusCode value is the HTTP status code, ie. 503
    if(500 -eq ($Response.StatusCode -as [int])){
        # Restart the app pool
        Restart-WebAppPool -Name $App.applicationPool
        }

    # Sleep for 5 minutes (300 seconds)
    Start-Sleep -s 300
}
```

Change the Website name and TestUri to yours.
This assume you depoly the webapplication directly to website. If you just add application underwebsite You can replace with

```
foreach($App in @(Get-WebApplication -Site 'Default Web Site')){

    # Uri for the application
    $TestUri = ''http://localhost/api/weatherforecast' -f $App.path
```

Editing and runing powershell script using PowerShell ISE by the way.

Comment: If I run the executable, and thus starting with Kestrel server directly - the process crashes and closes. But when IIS starts the executable through the AspNetCoreModuleV2Handler the executable is kept alive as a process, probably due to listening/attaching to the ports to which it communicates. If just it was crashing and closed - then IIS would know it is not there and restart.

Comment: We have some other tools on the server that could do the polling and killing of app pool/process. I would just prefer IIS could handle it, as some of our customers host this on-premise - and there we don't have infrastructure to monitor like we do for those we host.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no method within IIS if the worker process doesn't crash.  Script maybe the best solution here which could automatically restart application pool.